# Dump(item) not working in Twig template drupal

Tags: twig, drupal-8

I have twig template for default view

```
{% for item in items %}
     {{ item.content }}

    {% endfor %}
```

`{{ item.content }}` have values but when I tried to print the whole array like

```
 {% for item in items %}
         {{ item }}

        {% endfor %}
```

It is not working. I have enabled (service.yml)

```
debug true
cache false
autoload true
```

but it's not working. Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try and install the Devel plugin with its Kint extension. Once you have both running you could use: `{{kint(item.content)}}` to get a full list of all items within the content array.

Below an example of the kint() output.

[image: Example of an kint() dump]

As both are development plugins, they should only be used for debugging and not be installed on a production website.

Comment: thanks for the reply..i got null values..But actualy item.content have value

Comment: @shythyamenon Are you sure you are using the correct var, as when it does containt values Kint should show them. For example have you used `item` without content?

Answer (score 0):

Simple. add the **kint plugin** in composer.json

```
composer require kint-php/kint
```

then try with {{ dump('variable') }}
That's it.